# How to query for Author

Tags: javers

Using javers 1.4.10 and we try to display all objects which were changed by a certain user.

Is there any way to get the changes for a specific author? QueryBuilder & JqlQuery obviously do not offer an API to build a query

tnx & regards

Answer (score 0):

Not yet,
this frature is waiting in the JaVers backlog
https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/334